# Convert EPUB to TXT and preserve original formatting

Tags: text, calibre, epub

I have a programming book in EPUB format and I'm trying to convert it to TXT.
For that I'm using the utility **ebook-convert** from **calibre**.
The problem is that the standard usage:

```
ebook-convert book.epub book.txt
```

removes indentation in source code samples.
E.g. a sample in the book looks so:

```
class A {
  private int a;
}
```

But in the resulted TXT:

```
class A {
private int a;
}
```

After reading the utility's man page I've tried the following options:

```
--keep-ligatures
--pretty-print
--change-justification=original
```

but with no result. How to achieve it?

Comment: What OS and language settings are you using? Please recall that many docs are using *non-breaking spaces* (NBSP) that are coded into UTF-8 or with several other bytes, when not in ASCII. Try fiddle with your OS/terminal language or *locale* settings.

Comment: The book is english. I'm using Ubuntu 20. `$ locale
LANG=en_US.UTF-8`

Comment: @not2qubit Are you sure the utility shouldn't be responsible for this? For example the utility `pdftotext` has `-layout` option to keep original formatting of a PDF in TXT.

Comment: I have no idea. I just had a similar issue with OCR reading a PDF and prog was insisting to extract *nbsp*'s since the doc was coded in a foreign language.

Comment: you could convert to HTML (or just unzip the EPUB and use the HTML within directly) and try your luck with `links -dump` or similar. if that doesn't work either you might have to have a look at the HTML directly and write your own helper script for converting the code snippets.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Use [pandoc](https://pandoc.org/) instead of `ebook-convert`.  For example:

```
$ pandoc -f epub -t plain -o filename.txt filename.epub
```

I just tested this with a python epub, and it retained the indentation without a problem.

`pandoc` can also convert to other formats, including various flavours of markdown, asciidoc, latex, odt (Libre/Open Office text), rst, rtf, pdf, and more.

Comment: Yeah, I know the tool. Not sure why I've not tried it this time. The output looks good. The original indentation is preserved. Thanks!